# How to display error messages when using Hstore with simple_fields_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

How to display error messages when using Hstore with simple_fields_for?

I have a user model with hstore field `settings` with some validation:

```
store_accessor :settings, :attribute1, :attribute2
validates_presence_of :attribute1
```

And I use the following form:

```
simple_form_for :current_user do |f|
...
  f.simple_fields_for :settings, OpenStruct.new(current_user.settings) do |ff|
```

When I submit my form with an empty field for attribute1 I get no error messages displayed around the field.
How can I fix this?